# Updating a datatable in Wicket

Tags: ajax, datatable, wicket

We are developing a new application in Wicket and have run into a small problem.

What we do:

1) create a new SortableDataProvider
2) create a new DefaultDataTablePagingInBottom
3) create a new WebMarkupContainer
4) add the DefaultDataTablePagingInBottom to the WebMarkupContainer
5) create a new AjaxCheckBox
6) in the onUpdate of the AjaxCheckBox, add the WebMarkupContainer to the AjaxRequestTarget
7) set the SortableDataProvider to a new SortableDataProvider (with the updated query)
8) DefaultDataTablePagingInBottom.replaceWith(new DefaultDataTablePagingInBottom - with the new provider).

What happends:

1) Click the checkbox -> nothing happends.
2) Click it again -> crash: "Last cause: This method can only be called on a component that has already been added to its parent.
WicketMessage: Method onRequest of interface org.apache.wicket.behavior.IBehaviorListener targeted at org.apache.wicket.ajax.markup.html.form.AjaxCheckBox$1@1a2fefd on component [ [Component id = checkBox]] threw an exception"
3) Click back in the browser -> the list i filtered with the new provider.

Any ideas?

---EDIT---
Here's some code.

1) In the constructor of the WebPage:

```
model = new Model(projectPlannerService);
provider = new SortableProjectDataProvider(model, (WebSession) getSession(), isChecked);
table = new DefaultDataTablePagingInBottom("table", columns, provider, 50);

listContainer = new WebMarkupContainer("wmc");

listContainer.add(table);
add(listContainer.setOutputMarkupId(true));

/*
 * checkbox för filtrering
 */
AjaxCheckBox checkBox = new AjaxCheckBox("checkBox", new Model()) {

    @Override
    protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
        target.add(listContainer, "wmc");
        isChecked = !isChecked;
        provider = new SortableProjectDataProvider(model, (WebSession) getSession(), isChecked);
        updateTable();
    }
};
add(checkBox);
```

2) In updateTable():

```
table.replaceWith(new DefaultDataTablePagingInBottom("table", columns, provider, 50));
```

3) The SortableProjectDataProvider:

```
// Constructor
public SortableProjectDataProvider(IModel<?> model, WebSession webSession, boolean isChecked) {
    this.model = model;
    this.projectPlannerService = (ProjectPlannerService) model.getObject();
    this.webSession = webSession;
    setSort("customer", SortOrder.ASCENDING);
    System.out.println("ischecked:" + isChecked);
    if(!isChecked)
        list = ((ProjectPlannerService) model.getObject()).findAllProjects();
    else
        list = ((ProjectPlannerService) model.getObject()).findAllActiveProjects();

    System.out.println("size: " + list.size());

    comparator = new ProjectComparator();
}

public Iterator<Project> iterator(int first, int count) {

    Collections.sort(list, comparator);
    if (first > list.size()) {
        first = 0;
    }
    if (first + count > list.size()) {
        return list.subList(first, list.size()).iterator();
    } else {
        return list.subList(first, first + count).iterator();
    }
}

public IModel<Project> model(Project object) {
    return new DetachableProjectModel((Project) object);
}

public int size() {
    return list.size();
}


private class DetachableProjectModel extends LoadableDetachableModel {

    private Long id;
    @SpringBean
    ProjectPlannerService projectPlannerService;

    public DetachableProjectModel(Long id) {
        Injector.get().inject(this);
        if (id == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        this.id = id;
    }

    public DetachableProjectModel(Project project) {

        this(project.getPk());
        Injector.get().inject(this);
    }


    public int hashCode() {
        return id.hashCode();
    }


    public boolean equals(final Object obj) {
        if (obj == this) {
            return true;
        } else if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        } else if (obj instanceof DetachableProjectModel) {
            DetachableProjectModel other = (DetachableProjectModel) obj;
            return other.id == this.id;
        }
        return false;
    }


    protected Object load() {
        return ((ProjectPlannerService) model.getObject()).findProjectById(id);
    }
}
```

}

wicket:extend
   -input wicket:id="checkBox" type="checkbox"- Show active -/input-
   -div wicket:id="wmc"-
   -table wicket:id="table"--/table-
   -/div-
-/wicket:extend-

Thanks in advance!
/Andreas

Comment: Question is difficult to answer without code!

Answer (score 1):

By replacing the instance of your `SortableProjectDataProvider` with a new one you are making your life difficult. Instead of using the `boolean isChecked` in the constructor you could use an `IModel<Boolean>`. Assign the same instance of that model to your data provider and the check-box and you are done. No need to replace anything in `onUpdate`, add your `listContainer` to the `AjaxRequestTarget` and everything should just work...

e.g.

```
...

private IModel<Boolean> isCheckedModel = new Model<Boolean>(Boolean.FALSE);

...

provider = new SortableProjectDataProvider(model, (WebSession) getSession(), isCheckedModel);

...

AjaxCheckBox checkBox = new AjaxCheckBox("checkBox", isCheckedModel) {

    @Override
    protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
        target.add(listContainer);
    }
};

...
```

It is almost never a good idea to replace such things with new ones in Wicket. Encapsulate what changes in a model and change / replace the model's object. Every object that has a reference to that model can see the updated value or change it as needed.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Wrong: target.add(listContainer, "wmc");
Right: target.add(listContainer);

Wrong; table.replaceWith(new DefaultDataTablePagingInBottom("table", columns, provider, 50));
Right: DefaultDataTablePagingInBottom tmp = new DefaultDataTablePagingInBottom("table", columns, provider, 50); 
        table.replaceWith(tmp);
        table = tmp;
(You replace the DefaultDataTablePagingInBottom but not your reference.)

//olle